# Make Mac behave as a USB-Keyboard for another Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line, usb, automation

As part of a workgroup I am trying to run multiple bash commands in the recovery mode terminal.
Because we have a large collection of Macs, and because not all of my coworkers are experienced in scripting, I am looking to automate the process.

As another solution approach we have gathered all the commands in a scripts on a USB stick connected to the device, then execute the script with a USB-Scanner and a Barcode containing the execute command.

Is there a way to have our Mac behave as a USB-Keyboard to another Mac, and let it input those bash commands when the terminal is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered using a Mac was a lot more work in recovery than either a proper KVM or an inexpensive $10 arduino device and some Mac software designed to automate keystrokes.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it offers solutions for other issues we face as well.
But im unfamiliar with KVMs, would it be able to execute automated keystrokes, or does it just distribute the Keyboard input? If the latter, then do I still need a device like Arduino to output automated keystrokes, or is there a software solution for Mac that can send out those Keystrokes via USB?

Comment: @EddiKh get the arduino as the time and cost are lowest. KVM such as these are less time, more cost. https://www.kvm-switches-online.com/mac-kvm-switches.html doing a Mac only solution has a very large time effort to make that work. We didn’t invest that since the alternatives were far cheaper for us

Comment: Understood, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across an app called [KeyPad](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keypad-bluetooth-keyboard/id1491684442?mt=12), which I know allows me use my Bluetooth keyboard for both my Mac and my iPad or iPhone, and it says it would work for other Macs as well, so...

Comment: Hmm.  This might be difficult to get a macOS machine in recovery mode to successfully run an app like that without detailed guidance and setup.